# Dividing the workload among multiple application instances of spring batch

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a spring batch application which reads from mongo-db collection "A" which has executionDate same as current date. Currently we are processing around 2 million records. We want to scale up the spring batch application instances in order to divide the workload. Given that they will be reading from the same collection "A" with same query parameters how can we achieve efficient workload distribution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using [partitioning](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/scalability.html#partitioning). The idea is to create distinct partition and create a job instance per partition that you run in different JVMs and scale as needed.

You can also use a locally partitioned step with multiple threads in the same JVM. I would start with this setup before scaling to remote partitioning.